Remix - Parent loader throwing 500 and nested loader returning a redirect
Today I bumped into an unexpected behaviour from Remix and I'd like to understand if I'm missing something.
I have a loader in routes/main/loader.ts and another loader in routes/main._index/loader.ts.
There's a condition where the parent loader throws a 500 response and the nested loader returning a redirect. My expectation was for Remix to render the nearest ErrorBoundary, but what actually happens is that the redirect is performed despite the parent loader throws a 500.
I know that loaders are all called in parallel in Remix, but I was expecting that errors in parent loaders to still take priority.
Another interesting thing is that if I replace the line throwing a 500 with a redirect to another URL just for testing, the redirectis performed to that URL and not the one in the nested loader.
So it seems that in one case what happens in the parent loader has priority, and in others what happens to the child one has priority.

You might want to post your code for this - but if you are throwing the redirect maybe its actioning first before the loader would throw the error, as on redirect the loaders would reload.
